# Push value to nested array object by mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got following code:

```
var query = {
    "lessons.teacher": req.user._id,
    "lessons.units.name": req.body.unitName
};

var projection = {
    $push: {
        "lessons.0.units.$.topics": {
            "name": req.body.topicName
        }
    }
};

Class.findOneAndUpdate(query, projection, function (err, class) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.redirect('/topics');
});
```

I'd like to push topic name to lesson.units.topic. When I stay with following push projection:

```
"lessons.0.units.$.topics": {
    "name": req.body.topicName
}
```

It'll always add to first lessons array, however I'd like to push it to lessons array where following query meets requirement:

```
"lessons.units.name": req.body.unitName
```

Could you help me to understand what could I do to resolve that issue?
I've tried by using following projection:

```
var projection = {
    $push: {
        "lessons.$.units.$.topics": {
            "name": req.body.topicName
        }
    }
};
```

But I can't use more than one `$`

Comment: No you cannot. And your attempt to do this by "cheating" with `lessons.0` does not really matter since the [positional `$` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) will  **only ever** match the "outer" or "top level" array element only, an never anything "inner". The real lesson to learn here is *"Do not store nested arrays"* in your database, unless you are prepared to live without "atomic" updates. Yes there is a JIRA issue, and yes it is one of the oldest ones on file. I would not expect a resolution soon.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I only need to push to that array, do not remove/update

Comment: But a `$push` requires an "update" operation. The question really is do you need to match the "inner" position where you need to "push"? If not then it is okay. But if you do ( and your question implies array within array and another array inside that ) then it is not possible "atomically". The only way is to fetch the document, manipulate in code, then save the content back. And that is **bad** for soooo many reasons.

Comment: Well. Possibly a bit "harsh" a term ( beware that mormons lurk here ), but your schema design may not suit your "purposes". It's just a matter of working within the considerations. A bit hard to answer in your question format, as it is not really completely clear what your schema actually looks like, nor "all" of the actions you wish to use that data and format with. A wider picture ( and therefore probably multiple other quesstions ) would shed a bit more light on "what is right" for you.